# Site template using float

Tags: html, css, css-float

I found site template.

```
body {

    font: 10pt Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
    background: #54463d;
    margin: 0;
   }
   h2 {
    font-size: 1.1em;
    color: #752641;
    margin-bottom: 0;
   }
   #container {
    width: 500px;
    margin: 0 auto;
    background: #f0f0f0;
   }
   #header {
    background: #8fa09b;
    font-size: 24pt;
    font-weight: bold;
    color: #edeed5;
    padding: 5px;
   }
   #content {
    float: left;
    width: 329px;
    padding: 10px;
    border-right: 1px dashed #183533;
    background: #fff;
   }
   #content p {
    margin-top: 0.3em
   }
   #sidebar {
    float: left;
    width: 120px;
    padding: 10px;
   }
   #footer {
    background: #8fa09b;
    color: #fff;
    padding: 5px;
   }
   .clear { 
    clear: both;
   }
```

It works ok if content height more than menu height:
http://jsfiddle.net/R6MYH/1/
But, in another case, the site is not displayed correctly: 
http://jsfiddle.net/a5SFM/

Comment: Can you describe exacly what you mean by "not displayed correctly" pls

Comment: If you know the height of the sidebar, you can add `min-height: 150px` to the content div. - http://jsfiddle.net/a5SFM/2/

Comment: have a look at my answer. it will help you to solve your problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make slight change in your design as mentioned below :

1. Put divs with id **content** and **sidebar** inside one div with **float:left**
2. Remove **float:left** from css **#content** and **#sidebar**
3. Add **display:table-cell** in css **#content** and **#sidebar**

<kbd>[Live Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/a5SFM/5/)</kbd> This will work in all cases.

Your inner html will look like :

```
<div style="float:left">
      <div id="content">
       <h2>Title</h2>
       <p>There is only one sentence.</p>
   </div>
   <div id="sidebar">
    <p><a href="#">Lorem ipsum</a></p>
    <p><a href="#">Dolor sit amet</a></p>
    <p><a href="#">There is at text. Not really!</a></p>
    <p><a href="#">Link 4</a></p>
   </div>
      </div>
```

**Advantages:**

1. The main advantage of using display:table-cell is you don't have to set min-height. It will work even your side bar contains height of 1px.
2. More user friendly
3. Compatible in all the browsers (ie > 7)
4. You don't have to do any extra work like javascript/jquery.

Answer (score 1):

A more general solution, would be to implement this using JavaScript (jquery)

**Add this script to your document**

```
 $(document).ready(function () {
    $("#content").height($(window).height() - $("#header").height() - $("#footer").height() - 40);


});
```

This will make the content height as same as the browser's window height in all cases

**Don't forget to add this to inside your  tag**

```
 <script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Check it out here: http://jsfiddle.net/basharmadi/Mqy7y/

Comment: your script hid my footer

Comment: Sorry, I forgot about the footer. I updated my answer, and I think everything is good now.

Answer (score 1):

create a `div` inside `#container` and put `#content` and `#sidebar` inside it. 
and then replace `float: left` in css of both `#content` and `#sidebar` with `display: table-cell`

like this: http://jsfiddle.net/aneelkkhatri/a5SFM/6/
no use of `min-height`

Answer (score 0):

Try adding this to #content:

```
min-height:300px;
```

This will "extend" down the content div no matter what.

Answer (score 0):

Try to put a min-height to your content div:

```
min-height: 200px;
```

Here:

```
   #content {
    float: left;
    width: 329px;
    padding: 10px;
    border-right: 1px dashed #183533;
    background: #fff;
    min-height: 200px;
   }
```

[jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/a5SFM/3/)